# Bayesian Inference - Linear Regression with Gaussian Priors

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian, linear-regression, gaussian-integral

In a linear regression model ${\bf y} = {\bf x}^T {\bf w} + \epsilon$, assuming Gaussian noise ($\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma_n^2)$), and Gaussian priors on the weights (${\bf w}\sim N({\bf 0}, \Sigma_p))$, one can show that the posterior distribution for the weights given data $X,{\bf y}$ is also Gaussian, with:
$$p({\bf w}|X,{\bf y})\sim N\left(\bar{\bf w}=\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}A^{-1}X{\bf y}, A^{-1}\right)$$
Where $A = \sigma_n^{-2}X X^T + \Sigma_p^{-1}$.
In order to use this posterior to find the probability distribution $p(f({\bf x_*}))$ at some new point $\bf x_*$, we need to average over all possible weights (sometimes termed the Bayesian estimator):
$$p(f({\bf x_*})|{\bf x_*},X,{\bf y})=\int p(f({\bf x_*})|{\bf x_*},{\bf w})p({\bf w}|X,{\bf y})d\bf{w}$$
I'd like to prove that this is just the Gaussian:
$$\sim N\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}{\bf x_*}^T A^{-1}X {\bf y}, {\bf x_*}^T A^{-1}{\bf x_*}\right)$$
However, something in the integration doesn't seem to work out.

Can someone show how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something it should just be a straight forward application of the following

> If $\mathbf{P}$ is a linear transformation and
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> p(\mathbf{w}) &=\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{w}|\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}) \\
> p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{w}) &= \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{Pw}+\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{L}^{-1}),
> \end{align}
> $$
>   then
>   $$
> p(\mathbf{y})=\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{P}\boldsymbol{\mu}+\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{L}^{-1}+\mathbf{P}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}\mathbf{P}^T\right).
> $$

Now apply the above to the case that
$$
p(\mathbf{w}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{w}|\sigma_n^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Xy}, \mathbf{A}^{-1}),
$$
and so for this particular instance we have 
$$
\boldsymbol{\mu}:=\frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Xy}, \qquad \boldsymbol{\Lambda}:=\mathbf{A},
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{P}:=(\mathbf{x}_*)^T, \qquad \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}, \qquad \mathbf{L}^{-1}:= \sigma_n^2\mathbf{I}.
$$
Putting this together you get
$$
p(\mathbf{f}^*)=\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{f}^* \; \bigg| \; \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}\mathbf{x_*}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Xy}, \; \sigma_n^2\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{x}_*^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{x}_* \right),
$$
note the presence of the independent noise term, $\sigma_n^2\mathbf{I}$, in the predictive distribution.

I have left the conditioning on $\mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y}$ unstated but you can then go back and put that in by writing $p(\cdot) = p(\cdot | \mathbf{x}_*, \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y})$ if you like.

As an aside I am a little confused in this instance as to whether $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x})$, and therefore whether the noise $\epsilon$, intended to be vector or scalar valued but you can clean than up and make everything conform to the model you have in mind.

Comment: Were does one find the theorem you qouted? Do you know if there is a direct proof, or only one that goes through Bayes' theorem?

Comment: You can write $y=Pw + z$ with $z$ an independent Gaussian r.v. and then argue $p(y, x, z)$ are jointly Gaussian and then calculate moments

Comment: Or you could go directly with integration and rearranging the argument of the exponential term

Comment: Do you perhaps have a good reference book / paper on this and similar theorems?

Comment: What sort of level would you want the reference to be? There is discussion of this in Bishop' s Pattern Recog. and Machine Learning but maybe you want something a bit more in the lemma-proof style?

Comment: That's a good start, I was hoping there is a book that aggregates such results, not just those needed for the particular applied ML problem at hand.